# Graphical Layout Editor gives nullpointerexception for all XML files in eclipse Juno

Tags: android-layout, nullpointerexception, android-xml, eclipse-juno, eclipse-adt

the graphical layout editor in my eclipse stopped working, it gives me this message:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log
```

my Error Log has this in it:

```
eclipse.buildId=v21.1.0-569685
java.version=1.7.0_01
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2013-04-14 00:03:01.507
!MESSAGE Warning: EGit couldn't detect the installation path "gitPrefix" of native Git. Hence     
EGit can't respect system level
Git settings which might be configured in ${gitPrefix}/etc/gitconfig under the native Git    
installation directory.
The most important of these settings is core.autocrlf. Git for Windows by default sets this parameter to true in
this system level configuration. The Git installation location can be configured on the
Team > Git > Configuration preference page's 'System Settings' tab.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2013-04-14 00:03:08.208
!MESSAGE dialog_game_paused.xml: java.lang.NullPointerException
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.graphics.Bitmap_Delegate.nativeWidth(Bitmap_Delegate.java:291)
at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeWidth(Bitmap.java)
at android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth(Bitmap.java:909)
at android.graphics.Bitmap.getScaledWidth(Bitmap.java:957)
at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.computeBitmapSize(BitmapDrawable.java:179)
at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.setBitmap(BitmapDrawable.java:187)
at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.<init>(BitmapDrawable.java:555)
at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.<init>(BitmapDrawable.java:110)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.ResourceHelper.getDrawable(ResourceHelper.java:239)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.CustomBar.loadIcon(CustomBar.java:196)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.CustomBar.loadIconById(CustomBar.java:188)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.CustomBar.loadIconById(CustomBar.java:155)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.FakeActionBar.<init>(FakeActionBar.java:38)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:333)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:332)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:325)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:440)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.renderWithBridge(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1545)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.recomputeLayout(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1302)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.changed(GraphicalEditorPart.java:718)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.onTargetChange(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1189)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.LayoutEditorDelegate.onDescriptorsChanged(LayoutEditorDelegate.java:916)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.LayoutEditorDelegate.delegateInitUiRootNode(LayoutEditorDelegate.java:835)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart$TargetListener.updateEditor(GraphicalEditorPart.java:946)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart$TargetListener.onTargetLoaded(GraphicalEditorPart.java:910)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AdtPlugin$11.run(AdtPlugin.java:1754)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4144)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3761)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2701)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2665)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2499)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:679)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:668)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at  org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
```

I don't think I have a problem with my code because everything was working properly for a while and then 3 days ago it just happened.

Comment: same issue here... did you manage to fix it yet?